# Soxhlet extraction condenser - addition of compound to refluxing setup

Tags: organic-chemistry, equipment

I've never used Soxhlet apparatus before and I have troubles understanding how to properly perform the following step from my protocol:

> To a gently refluxing suspension of 1 g Lithium aluminium hydride in 100 mL of diethyl ether, there was added 1.2 g of compound as a saturated diethyl ether solution with use of a Soxhlet extraction condenser which is modified allowing the continuous return of condensed solvent (through the thimble). After the addition was complete, the refluxing conditions were maintained."

Soo... How do I do it? I run RBF with condenser on top until reflux stabilizes and then I open it, add Soxhlet with compound and continue refluxing or I set up everything cold (RBF with ether + Soxlet with compound in ether + condenser) and then start refluxing?

Also - I'm not quite sure if I understand the thimble modification - can anyone shed some light on it for me?

Comment: Puzzling indeed

Comment: Perhaps it is so. ... They place the 1.2 g of compound in the thimble. At beginning.  The gently refluxing do the rest by dropping diethyl ether to the thimble. You get a kind of gentle addition of an almost saturated solution filtered by the thimble dropping down to the reaction flask. They basically innested a syphon at the bottom of the soxhlet .It seems a clever way to slowly add the compound without opening the systems with volatile solvents. This offer the way to keep a fixed volume of solvent all through the reaction.. But this means sacrificing a soxhlet and skill on molding glass. ..

Comment: Obviously if compound does not readily dissolve in diethyl ether.

Comment: It's such a pity the creator (Sasha Shulgin) of the protocol passed away. He would have loved to chat with you about it I am sure. I just read it from the good book myself and arrived here after puzzling over it as well.

Comment: i suspect it is possible that the confusion results from careless ambiguous language describing a standard Soxhlet process. The point is that a saturated ether solution of the compound *results* from putting the compound in the thimble of a Soxhlet apparatus so the resulting liquid is saturated when it leaves the thimble and is returned to the reaction.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the intention is to have a very slow addition of the reagent to the hydride. The compound is dissolved in ether, so a Soxhlet is of no use since it is for solids.

What they are possibly referring to is a liquid-liquid extraction apparatus, specifically the one for extracting with solvents lighter than water:

[image]

The saturated solution of the compound is then placed in the thimble and when reflux starts, the solvent is condensed, falls into the tube and returns to the flask carrying over the compound. Normally the tube goes to the very bottom of the thimble. In fact, usually it is a loose tube with a wide opening on the top. How to know that the addition is complete is another story. If the compound is not colored, it will not be easy without opening the system.  In any case, maintaining reflux for a long time will ensure that everything goes into the flask.

I suppose that for some reason it is difficult to perform a slow addition through a funnel in this case. It would be, however, better to use a syringe pump but not everybody has one of those.

Comment: Yes but why to call it modify soxhlet?  I really think of something as in my comments. In that case addition is completed when no solid remains in the paper thimble .surely not a clear description anyway....

Comment: Modified in the sense that it is not an extraction. It is also said that a "saturated solution" is placed in the thimble, which is not posible in a Soxhlet with a bypassed siphon. Anyway, without some more information we can only guess.

Comment: Understand. But I would have written liq liq extractor :) I thought they were forming a saturated solution drop by drop. But in your case, why not to use a dropping fumnel and just a bit more solvent. I just tried to help.

Comment: True. As I have said in the answer, I suppose that there might be some problem for using a funnel. This is many times the case when volumes are small. Increasing the volume for having a slower addition might lead to other problems. By using this setup the addition is slow and the volumes remain constant as you have pointed out already.

Comment: Thank you for great responses so far!
Indeed - the protocol is quite minimalistic, but it was writen by a proffesional. Which I`m not :D The reflux conditions are supposed to last for 48 h, and the compound is yellow so I guess I`ll notice the addition. Corect me if I`m wrong, but wouldn`t it be simpler to omit the thimble completly? Just fill the Soxhlet with saturated solution of compound, set everything and star slow reflux. Refluxed solvent would slowly dilute compound and add it dropwise to LAH. Am I not seeing something?

Comment: If you do that, when the Soxhlet is full, the whole volume will be siphoned into the flask adding all the compound at once. Then there is no slow addition, which is what @Alchimista and myself think that is the reason for this non-conventional setup. The Soxhlet is normally used to extract solids. The solid is placed in a bag of filter paper in the thimble. The solvent is refluxed and, after condensing, it fills the thimble. The solid is extracted with the liquid. Then, when the thimble is full, the liquid is discharged into the flask through the siphon.

Comment: My last. In my idea the total volume remains 100 ml , that of refluxing hydride slt. I think I will use my setup if I would have a really modified soxhlet, I.e. syphon at botton , or I can even think of other setups let the condensing solv drop to the compound. If I would have an extractor I could use Raul setup. Total vol 100 plus that of tge sat solution.

Comment: @Alchimista in the liquid-liquid extractor the volume also remains constant. It flows over from the thimble, so you place the water phase inside and then you must fill it to the top with solvent so that the volume remains constant in the flask. Otherwise, the empty volume would be filled up with distilled solvent from the flask. In this case, the solution with the compound should fill the whole thimble. Since the volume is usually large, it would help to dissolve the product while not increasing the volume of reaction.

Comment: Ok ,I  overlooked that  poiny ,now I see.  But I was not taking it as a flaw.  It is just that we are somehow guessing.  Not to say that if compound is rather soluble I would go carefullu with a dropping funnel (it shouldn't be the case else the protocol does not make sense).